# phpinfo() causing 503 service temporarily unavailable error

Tags: php, apache, nginx, http-status-code-503

I'm experiencing the weirdest problem.  I've been working on a file upload problem for the last few days and have been using `phpinfo()` to track changes to INI settings.  The last time I touched it was two days ago... it all worked then.

Today, `phpinfo()` is causing a 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable error.  Here's the weird part: *the website works fine!*  I's PHP + MySQL driven and I can move around in it just fine (well... other than the issues I'm working on).  But as soon as I add `phpinfo()` to show up as the first thing in the `<body>` block... I get the error.

I've even tried creating a one-line file: `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`  This dies with a 503 error, too.

The error log contains this:

> [Fri Sep 15 14:22:31.192593 2017] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 2695] (104)Connection reset by peer: [client 67.161.220.240:44230] AH01075: Error dispatching request to :

I've restarted Apache and Nginx with no errors. Does anyone have an idea about what service or some such might have died on my machine to cause this?

**NGINX Config File**

```
#user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;

#error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
#error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log  notice;
#error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log  info;

#pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

include /etc/nginx/modules.conf.d/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
include       mime.types;
default_type  application/octet-stream;

#log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
#                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
#                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

#access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

sendfile        on;
#tcp_nopush     on;

#keepalive_timeout  0;
keepalive_timeout  65;
#tcp_nodelay        on;

#gzip  on;
#gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\.(?!.*SV1)";

server_tokens off;

include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}

# override global parameters e.g. worker_rlimit_nofile
include /etc/nginx/*global_params;
```

Comment: Are you hosting your own site, and if so do you manage the PHP installation?  `phpinfo` is often viewed as a security hole and turned off by SysAdmins

Comment: Side note, you don't have to echo phpinfo(). It echos itself. (But that shouldn't cause this problem, just fyi.)

Comment: Show nginx configuration. The php part.

Comment: @sensorario, added.

Comment: @jhenderson2099, I host my own site.  As mentioned, this all worked two days ago.

Comment: @Don'tPanic.  :-}  You're correct.  It's not working without the `echo`, either.

Comment: Have you updated you PHP version recently?  If you haven't, then, if you create a new, simple PHP application under the same site, and dump `phpinfo` does that work?  

If 'yes', then it is specific to your application (perhaps a syntax error).  If 'no' then `phpinfo` has been disabled for the entire instance.

Comment: @jhenderson2099, I have not updated PHP recently.  I have a single php file (`test.php`) in the domain webroot with `<php phpinfo(); ?>`.  I can execute `php -f test.php` and it works fine, but if I try to access it via `http://example.com/test.php` I get the 503 error.  I've never disabled phpinfo before and don't understand why it would be disabled.  I don't even know how to do it.

Comment: After doing some research, I don't think that `phpinfo` is disabled.  If it was, then it should just be an empty string.  

An HTTP 503 means 'Service Unavailable'.  Can you access any other PHP functions (e.g. `phpversion`) via the web server and or `php -f`?

Comment: Also, do you have any PHP extensions that you might be using?

Comment: @jhenderson2099 `phpversion()` works just fine.  No 503 error.  It appears to only be `phpinfo()`.  Remember, the site itself is written in PHP and it's working fine.  I do have extensions, such as ImageMagick, which I use on my site.  I just tested the image upload function (which uses ImageMagick) and it's working fine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154571/discussion-between-jhenderson2099-and-jbh).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it possible that this is the problem:
[Apache, FastCGI - Error 503](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12267618/apache-fastcgi-error-503)

(i.e. a Fast CGI configuration issue?)

Answer (score -1):

I solved this by logging into PLESK. I went to  Tools & Settings -> Services Management.

Then I restarted PHP-FPM 5.6.33 service (this may vary depending on the version of PHP you are running).

After a re-start, `phpinfo()`worked fine.  I'm not sure what the issue was.  As you experienced, my website was working fine but it may have been causing other issues I'm not aware of.